# Internal Server Error Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

i added secrets.yml to gitignore,and i keep having this error message on heroku

"Internal Server Error
Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`",

please how do i add my ENV variables without committing secrets.yml to my repo.

Comment: [This?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can log onto your [Heroku Dashboard](https://id.heroku.com/), select the desired app (that assumed you might have more than 1 app in Heroku), click the `Settings` link for that application, then click the `Reveal Config Vars` button and finally, edit and change and add to your heart's content!

You can also use the Heroku command-line integration to accomplish this but the Web UI is often easier if you're first getting started with Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, put your file `secrets.yml` back to you

`secrets.yml`

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %>
```

2. As you see above, the secret key & token are the environment variables. Then you just update these values in your [heroku settings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: So you mean i should add  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %>

Comment: to variable setting on heroku?